# Appcelerator / Titanium Alloy - how to manipulate a string before it gets added to the view

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium Alloy view, which outputs a `TableView` with an image thumbnail for each one. This is achieved by passing a URL into the `image` attribute of the `ImageView` element. As it is an Alloy view populated by an Alloy collection, it handles the looping of data for me:

```
<TableView id="brandsList" dataCollection="brands">
    <TableViewRow brandID="{brand_id}">
        <View class="vgroup">
            <ImageView height="45" width="80" id="image" image="{image}" />
            <Label id="name" text="{name}" />   
        </View>             
    </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

However, I'd like to change that URL string a bit **before** it gets to the view above. Specially I need add some values in the middle of the URL which change the image quality and size. How can I catch this string string value and make my changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the looks of this code it appears you are doing data-binding. you can transform data before it is presented in the view

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding

```
<TableView id="brandsList" dataCollection="brands"  dataTransform="transformFunction">
    <TableViewRow brandID="{brand_id}">
        <View class="vgroup">
            <ImageView height="45" width="80" id="image" image="{image}" />
            <Label id="name" text="{name}" />   
        </View>             
    </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

then in the code

```
function transformFunction(model) {
    // Need to convert the model to a JSON object
    var transform = model.toJSON();
    transform.image = /* do someting to image url string */;
    return transform;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why we need to convert the model to a JSON object?

Comment: that is just how the transformation works, you are passing a JSON object to be rendered in the UI, not the backbone model